# SQL Inner Join and Natural Join

Tags: mysql, join

so I have a some specific questions in regards to an old exam paper I'm working on, in preperation for an actual exam. This is on an extremely basic level, but I just needed help with understanding the results of some specific assignments.

Inner Join and Natural join:

[image: I do apologize for uploading it in image]

form, hope thats okay. 
My first question is in regards to 1. where the statement reads:

```
Select * From r INNER JOIN s ON r.F=s.F
```

Why when doing an Inner Join does 12 get removed in row E and not 20?

The second question is in regards to the following statement:

```
Select E, G From r NATURAL JOIN s;
```

Again, is it specifically 12 thats removed from row E and not 20?

Again I apologize for the terrible set-up with the image and what not, hope someone can explain the result of this very simple assignment to me.

Thanks in advance

Kind regards

Comment: E is not a row; why do you think 12 should be included and/or 20 shouldn't?

Comment: Only data that matches on the joined values from both tables will be returned (thus is the nature of an INNER join).  So since F is the column being joined, only values 5,10,15 could POSSIBLY be joined. and since 5,15,20 are in the second table.  the only intersection of values is on values 5 and 15.  Thus all other ROWS are excluded.  A natural join is similar but joins on LIKE column names between the tables since r and s only have F as a same column name, they are joined and the results match that of the inner join.

Comment: Man I'm an idiot, I completely understand it now, don't know how I couldn't see that, I appologize for wasting everyones time!

Comment: user1845777, I answered to you the first question, so you can think the second one, let me know if you don't get it

Comment: @user1845777 hahah don't be so dramatic :D, we are trying to help! this site has some rules to ask ans to add answers too, so the site can be everyday better and better, so don't get sad if you don't ask a perfect question the first 5 times, I still can ask a good good question so far... I found a little bit hard, but you can always edit the question with the suggestions of the other users, everyone here wants to help

Comment: Furthermore answer C is a representation of an outer join, specifically `FROM R LEFT JOIN S on R.F=S.F`  I've seen mySQL do B (on natural joins so B may in fact be a correct result may depend on mySQL engine though) if column names are not aliased but most engines would throw an error or alias the columns _1 etc.... and D is an impractical result as 10 and 20 don't match.  it could be possible to achieve D if we assigned a row number 1-3 for each table and joined on that row number preserving order in each of the defined tables; but then it's just dumb luck that 5 goes w/ 5 and 15 with 15.

Comment: Here's an example on a natural join of select * only returning 1 f column: http://rextester.com/FNT36037

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select * From r INNER JOIN s ON r.F=s.F
```

result will be

```
E  F  F  G
10 5  5 30
20 15 15 20
```

The INNER JOIN keyword selects records that have matching values in both tables. This is why 12 is removed ie, no common column.
Now the result for

```
Select E, G From r NATURAL JOIN s
```

is

```
E  G
10 30
20 20
```

when you use * on select you get

```
F  E   G
5  10 30
15 20 20
```

while using * on natural join it will be expanded to the following list of columns

- All the common columns
- Every column in the first (left) table that is not a common column
- Every column in the second (right) table that is not a common column

Comment: and a nice link to rextester so you can play @user1845777 http://rextester.com/TQOGJ53943

Answer (score 0):

To understand the diferent types of joins take a look of this:
[image]

So as you can see, the inner you match the elements the both table has in common, in your case:

r has [5,15,20] in the F column
a has [5,15,20] in the F column

so as result, the values will be [5,15], and as you did a select *, it will select all columns from both tables, but without repeat the name with columns in common

```
Select * From r INNER JOIN s ON r.F=s.F
```

Result table r:

```
E   F  G
10  5  20
20  15 30
```

Comment: No.  Natural joins consolidate the same named columns, so you would only have 3.  Inner join will keep all 4.  http://rextester.com/FNT36037  I don't believe @damianLattenero's result table is correct. but it may be configurable to do this.  Natural and Inner join behave differently in the rextester link above.

Comment: But since its specifically E, G wouldn't it then only create two columns named E and G

Comment: @user1845777 exactly what xQbert said! See? Nobody judging your question, everybody helping

Comment: @user1845777 no.  consolidate column names, not remove them. the Select * means all columns so on an inner join you get 4 columns.  a natural join however consolidates the liked name columns as the values are the same; so E,G, F (there were 2 f's now there's 1 consolidated in the natural join)

Comment: ah I missread the natural join... Yes only E,G since those are the values selected.